# How to I get a correct average number of appointments per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see what the average number of appointments is by each appointment type is. Basically I have the following tables and columns:

```
Table 1 - Dates
-----------
Date date (primary key)

Table 2 - Appointments
-----------
AppointmentStart Datetime
ApptId Numeric
FacilityId Numeric
ApptKind Numeric
Appointmentid Numeric

Table 3 AppointmentType
-----------
ApptTypeId Numeric
Name Varchar


Sample Data
============

Table 1 Date
--------------- 
date
1/1/2017
1/2/2017
...

Table 2 Appointment
----------------  
ApptStart        |  ApptTypeId   | FacilityId   |  ApptKind |  ApptId
2017-1-1 9:00:00    1              2               1           2385525
2017-1-1 9:15:00    3              2               1           2385526
2017-1-1 9:30:00    2              2               1           2385527
...


Table 3 ApptType
-----------------
ApptTypeId  |  Name
1              Walk-in
2              MAT
3              Acute
...
```

There are about 30 different appointment types and not all of them occur every day. So far I have created a table that lists every date in the time range that I want then I do a left join with the count of appointments (nulls equal 0). I also remove Saturdays and Sundays. This works really well for one appointment type but when I do this with multiple appointment types zeroes only show up for the days where there are no appointments.

My solution:
Somehow insert each appointment type next to each day then do the left join with the NULL = 0 part although I don't know how to get the list to repeat for each day in the table.

Example:

At the end I want

```
EndResult
----------
Average(Count(appts)) |  ApptType.Name
```

OR

```
EndResult
---------
Count(apptid)  |  ApptType.Name  |  Date
5                 Acute             1/1/2017
0                 MAT               1/1/2017
4                 Walk-in           1/1/2017
0                 Other             1/1/2017
```

Then repeat for the next day with the same appointment type names

Comment: please add sample data and desired output

Comment: With your current data structure you will have to hard code the appointment types into the query. Ideally you would have another table with appointment types. You could then do a full outer join on a true value (where 1=1) to get a Cartesian result of your dates and appointment types. From there you could join table 2 on date and ApptType using an ISNULL(count(*),0) to return each appointment type for each date, even for dates without and records of that appointment type.

Comment: average appointment by day or week? what is the time frame?

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien Could you explain that a little bit more? I do actually have a different table with the appointment types. I'm not sure if there are any true values they could join on? Thank  you for your response, I'm pretty new to sql so this is all a little confusing.

Comment: Since I can't post an answer I'll see how this posts in a comment.First we get the cartesian product of a full outer join of Dates and ApptType. "SELECT
 [Dates].[Date]
 ,[ApptType].[ApptTypeID]
 ,[ApptType].[Name]
FROM Dates AS [Dates]
FULL OUTER JOIN ApptType AS [ApptType]
 ON 1 = 1". We can use the cartesian product as our left data set, and count/avg/other aggregation of items in our right data set (Appointments).

Comment: An example would be "SELECT
 A.[Date]
 ,A.[Name]
 ,ISNULL(COUNT(B.Appointmentid), 0) AS [Appointments]
FROM (
 SELECT
  [Dates].[Date]
  ,[ApptType].[ApptTypeID]
  ,[ApptType].[Name]
 FROM Dates
 FULL OUTER JOIN ApptType
  ON 1 = 1) AS A
LEFT JOIN Appointments AS B
 ON A.[ApptTypeId] = B.[ApptId]
GROUP BY
 A.[Date]"

Comment: I noticed that `ApptTypeID` is NOT in your first list of `Table2`, and then it is shown in your second portrayal of `Table2` - so is `ApptTypeID` in `Table2` or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write a query that gets you to
End Result #2:

```
SELECT IsNull(B.ApptCount, 0) AS ApptCount, C.Name AS ApptTypeName, A.Date
FROM (
    SELECT Table1.Date, Table3.ApptTypeID
    FROM Table1, Table3
) AS A LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Convert(Date, ApptStart) AS ApptDate, ApptTypeID, COUNT(ApptID) AS ApptCount 
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Date(ApptStart), ApptTypeID
) AS B ON A.Date = B.ApptDate AND A.ApptTypeID = B.ApptTypeID
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS C ON B.ApptTypeID = C.ApptTypeID
```

This assumes that `ApptTypeID` is indeed part of Table2.  You can wrap this result up further to get your End Result #1:

```
SELECT Avg(D.ApptCount), D.ApptTypeName 
FROM (
    SELECT IsNull(B.ApptCount, 0) AS ApptCount, C.Name AS ApptTypeName, A.Date
    FROM (
        SELECT Table1.Date, Table3.ApptID
        FROM Table1, Table3
    ) AS A LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Convert(Date, ApptStart) AS ApptDate, ApptTypeID, COUNT(ApptID) AS ApptCount 
        FROM Table2
        GROUP BY Date(ApptStart), ApptTypeID
    ) AS B ON A.Date = B.ApptDate AND A.ApptTypeID = B.ApptTypeID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS C ON B.ApptTypeID = C.ApptTypeID
) AS D
GROUP BY D.ApptTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

First we declare and populate table variables for example data.

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (
    Date DATE
)

INSERT @Dates
VALUES
    ('2017-01-01')
    ,('2017-01-02')

DECLARE @Appointments TABLE (
    AppointmentStart DATETIME
    ,ApptId INT
    ,FacilityId INT
    ,ApptKind INT
    ,Appointmentid INT
)

INSERT @Appointments
VALUES
    ('2017-01-01 09:00:00.000', 1, 2, 1, 2385525)
    ,('2017-01-01 09:15:00.000', 3, 2, 1, 2385526)
    ,('2017-01-01 09:30:00.000', 2, 2, 1, 2385527)

DECLARE @ApptType TABLE (
    ApptTypeId INT
    ,Name VARCHAR(32)   
)

INSERT @ApptType
VALUES
    (1, 'Walk-in')
    ,(2, 'MAT')
    ,(3, 'Acute')
```

This shows us the cartesian product of a full outer join of Dates and ApptType.

```
SELECT
    [Dates].[Date]
    ,[ApptType].[ApptTypeID]
    ,[ApptType].[Name]
FROM @Dates AS [Dates]
FULL OUTER JOIN @ApptType AS [ApptType]
    ON 1 = 1
```

We can use the cartesian product as our left data set, and count the number of items in our right data set (@Appointments). By doing this with a left join, we ensure that every date/appointment type combination is included, even if there were no appointments of that type on that date.

```
SELECT
    A.[Date]
    ,A.[Name]
    ,COUNT(B.Appointmentid)
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Dates].[Date]
        ,[ApptType].[ApptTypeID]
        ,[ApptType].[Name]
    FROM @Dates AS [Dates]
    FULL OUTER JOIN @ApptType AS [ApptType]
        ON 1 = 1) AS A
LEFT JOIN @Appointments AS B
    ON A.[ApptTypeId] = B.[ApptId]
    AND A.[Date] = CAST(B.[AppointmentStart] AS DATE)
GROUP BY
    A.[Date]
    ,A.[Name]
ORDER BY
    A.[Date]
    ,A.[Name]
```